# Could not load assembly 'CommonBaseData'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'CommonBaseType'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, migration, microservices

I want create micro service architecture solution so I add some services for my solution. All my services must have one table in my database in there models so I add write this migrations for add one table from my database:

```
 Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=DESKTOP-9Q51Q00\TMF;Database=DataModelSection;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Model -Tables tblCommonBaseType -Context "Contexts"
```

The table which I want from my database successfully:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzuZr.png)

but when I create project #2 and I want to use this migration, and add one more table, I get an error and the build fails.

```
 Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=DESKTOP-9Q51Q00\TMF;Database=DataModelSection;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Model -Tables tblCommonBaseData -Context "Contexts"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDUUo.png)

Comment: Open the Error window and check what is the problem.

Comment: Could not load assembly 'CommonBaseData'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'CommonBaseType'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error often caused when the current project is **not the startup project**.

You can right click the project and click 'set as a startup project'

Looks like you want to share the same database between two projects?

You can **move the Entity Framework code into a shared class library** and reference it in

two projects, no need to scaffold twice with the same database, it may occur some
conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try right clicking on the solution and clicking on "Set as Startup Project"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call the database from MVC Project to your API and you have an error like that, try to click on your API project and then Set as startup project then try to Scaffold again. It will work this time.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error even though the right project was defined in Solution Explorer.
In Visual Studio, you need to make sure that the "Default project" selector points to the right project.

**See Default project option**

[image]